# How to remove icon from QMessageBox in PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qmessagebox

I am trying to code a message box that just pops up and says something and has a single button to close it however as I only have a small amount of text in the box the icon/image to the left of it is huge and looks bad. I want to know how to remove it. I am also having trouble making custom message boxes. Tutorials say that this is how you make a custom message box:

```
box = QMessageBox()
box.setText('text')
box.addButton(QPushButton('Close', self))
box.exec_()
```

However this just closes my program and returns a 1. My current code uses the about method of QMessageBox():

```
box = QMessageBox().about(self, 'About', 'This is a test Program')
```

However this has that large icon in the text window and I can't seem to do anything else to the box as it just stops the program and returns 1 again

I am in desperate need of some decent PyQt documentation. I can't seem to find documentation on much at all unless it is in C++. For instance I cannot seem to find any information of options other than question and about for QmessageBox. So if someone could also show me where some proper documentation lives it would prevent me asking too many questions here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than PyQt documentation, it is better to directly use Qt documentation. You only need to switch your language mindset from Python to C++, there and back. It is not that difficult. :) See e.g. http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmessagebox.html#addButton or http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmessagebox.html#about I think this is very detailed documentation, unrivaled by most other frameworks.

Note that there are three overrides of `addButton()`. From the documentation it seems that you either need to pass two arguments to `box.addButton(QPushButton('Close', self), QMessageBox.RejectRole)` (you forgot the role!) or better, you use the override which uses standard buttons, then you only pass one argument: `box.addButton(QMessageBox.Close)`.

And one more tip for you: I also find it easier to debug my program with `PySide` than `PyQt` because unlike `PyQt`, `PySide` catches the exception, prints that to console and keeps running. While `PyQt` usually just silently crashes leaving you clueless. Most of the time, I am using shims `Qt.py` https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Qt.py/0.6.9 or `qtpy` https://pypi.python.org/pypi/QtPy to be able to switch from `PyQt` to `PySide` on the fly. It also allows switching between `Qt4` and `Qt5` bindings easily.

Comment: The problem with that is that I know very little C++. I tried learning it ages ago but never got far. I was also concerned about possible differences between them

Right so it does work with a role which is great however my text and button seems to be aligned to the right now in the box. What is the method of changing their position?

Can the icon not be removed from a built in like question or about?

Comment: But you do not need C++ to understand that documentation. Just replace `::` with `.` and that is it. :) According to the docs, it seems that the icon cannot be changed in the 'about' message box unless you change the application icon or the parent window icon. If you have created your own application icon, then you may be just need to use a smaller version of it (say 128x128 pixels or something like that). I personally think it is nice to have the application logo in the about box.

Comment: You can easily trap exceptions in PyQt by setting sys.excepthook. But I agree with VK that you don't need to know C++ to figure out the docs, all class, function and arg names are identical, all you need to do is ignore types. The examples tend to be a little more difficult to translate, but Pyqt comes with lots of examples translated from C++ to Python.

Comment: Alright that works for me then. After some research I think I will switch to pyside. Is everything essentially the same in pyside? Can I still use those docs because that works for me I was mostly worried about differences in how they worked

Comment: The biggest disadvantage of `PySide` is that at the moment it allows only `Qt4` and that is REALLY BAD if you want your program to be future-proof. There is currently `PySide2` project underway but you have to compile it yourself (I heard the precompiled binaries are availabl on Ubuntu 15.xx or 16.xx, but I cannot verify that). The best solution is to use the shims which I mentioned in the answer above. They allow you developing like you were using `Qt5` (while actually using `Qt4` in the background) and switch easily to `PySide2` later when it is available.

Comment: Thx to Schollii for pointing to `sys.excepthook`. This is really useful.

Comment: It's actually a bug that PySide keeps running after an unhandled exception - a normal python script would never behave that way. PyQt4 also had this bug, but it's been fixed in PyQt5.

Comment: @JohnO'Neil you say "after some research, ... I will switch to pyside", what are your reasons? PyQt is keeping up with Qt and is very usable, whereas Pyside has stalled (so as much as I like open source projects, there are many important changes happening in Qt that you should at least have the choice to use).

Comment: @Schollii There might be licensing issues. PySide is LGPL while PyQt is GPL or commercial. Despite the fact that there have been lots of new stuff in Qt recently added, if you develop widget based application, you actually do not need most of the new stuff. Btw. PySide2 is on the way...